# how to read all json data with different names

Tags: javascript, json

i'm trying trying to get json data with different names

```
var ITEMLIST = {'ITEMS': [
{
'IceCream': 'ItemName': 'cookie', price: 200,
'pizza': { 'ItemName': 'pizza', price: 300,} 
]}

function UpdateItemList(myJSON){ // I got this code from stack overflow :)
    if(myJSON){
    for(let i = 0; i < myJSON.length; i++){
        if(i !== null){
            console.log(myJSON)
}
}
}

UpdateItemList(ITEMLIST.ITEMS)
```

**Iv'e tried multiple times to fix this but it just wont work**
**, Thanks**

Comment: I am not sure exactly what kind of output you are expecting to get out of the function because the `ITEMLIST` appears to be missing some brackets. It would help the answerers if you could show what sort of output you are expecting, and how many times you expect `console.log()` to be called. It may help attract people if you [edit]ed your question to add the [javascript] tag, indent all the code, and add the missing brackets to your JSON.

Comment: your JSON data is invalid. check it again. Check explanation on how to fix it by copying your code to the textbox on [JSON Formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var ITEMLIST = {'ITEMS': [
       {
         'IceCream': { 'ItemName': 'cookie', price: 200 },
         'pizza':    { 'ItemName': 'pizza',  price: 300 } 
       }
    ]
}

function UpdateItemList(myJSON) { // I got this code from stack overflow :)
    if(myJSON) {
      for(let i = 0; i < myJSON.length; i++) {
          if(i !== null) {
              console.log(myJSON)
          }
       }
    }
}

UpdateItemList(ITEMLIST.ITEMS);
```

Here is your valid json data

But why you don't use console.log(ITEMSLIST.ITEMS)? -> gives you the same output

Comment: Ok but i want to use my json data, Thank you tho!

Comment: Ok but i want to use my json data, Thank you tho!